# IE8 loses cookies when opening a new window after a redirect

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8

I'm using Internet Explorer 8 beta 2.

1. Client performs POST on http://alpha/foo
2. Server responds with redirect to http://beta/bar
3. Client performs GET on http://beta/bar
4. Server responds with redirect to http://beta/baz and sets cookie
5. Client performs GET on http://beta/baz *including cookie*
6. Server provides response
7. User selects "Open in new window" on a link in the page
8. Client performs GET on http://beta/link, *without cookie!*

If in step 7 the user just clicks the link, the cookie *is* passed correctly.  If there is no redirect, the cookie is passed correctly even if the user selects "Open in new window".

Is there a way to convince IE8 to pass the cookie in step 8?

(Edit: I believe this is a bug in IE8 beta 2, so I've [raised it on the IE beta newsgroup](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/list/en-us/default.aspx?mid=f90dfed8-42e3-499a-9a0b-4eefa66efccc&dg=microsoft.public.internetexplorer.beta).  Workaround suggestions welcome.)

Comment: IE8 Beta 2 had lots of bugs with LCIE where cookies would get lost in new windows. Those issues were fixed in the RC and RTM builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that IE8 uses a separate process for each window. If you're using session cookies, the new process will start with a fresh session and therefore won't be able to submit the session cookies received by the other process. Can you try using persistent cookies and see what happens?

From http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/beta/readiness/developers-existing.aspx#lcie

> Loosely-coupled Internet Explorer
>   (LCIE) is an architectural effort to
>   improve the browser by separating its
>   components and loosening their
>   interdependence: most notably, it is
>   an attempt to isolate the Internet
>   Explorer frame and its tabs into
>   separate processes. In Internet
>   Explorer 8, this isolation will bring
>   about improved performance and
>   scalability, as well as more potent
>   methods to recover from problems like
>   disk or system failure.

Comment: Thanks - persistent cookies do work.  But that would be a pretty invasive change to my application.  Do you think this is a bug?  Note that if steps 2 through 5 are omitted (i.e., there is no redirect), "open new window" *does* preserve session cookies.  That seems inconsistent.