# IE8 losing session cookies in popup windows

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8, popup

We have an ASP.NET application that uses Forms Auth. When users log in, a session ID cookie and a Forms Auth ticket (stored as a cookie) are generated. These are session cookies, not permanent cookies. It is intentional and desirable that when the browser closes, the user is effectively logged out.

Once a user logs in, a new window is popped up using `window.open('location here');`. The page that is opened is effectively the workspace the user works in throughout the rest of their session. From this page, other pop-ups are also used.

Lately, we've had a number of customers (all using latest versions of IE8) complaining that the when they log in, the initial pop-up takes them back to the log in screen rather than their homepage. Alternately, users can sometimes log in, get to the homepage (which again, is in a new pop up window), and it all seems fine, until any additional pop-ups are created, where it starts redirecting them to the log in screen again.

In attempting to troubleshoot the issue, I've used good old Fiddler. When the problem starts manifesting, I've noticed that the browser is not sending up the ASP.NET session ID session cookie OR the Forms Auth ticket session cookie, even though the response to the log in POST clearly pushes down those cookies.

What's more strange is if I CTRL+N to open a new window from the popped-up window that is missing the session cookies, then manually type in the URL to the home page, those cookies magically appear again. However, subsequent `window.open();` calls will continue to be broken, not sending the session cookies and taking the user to the log in screen.

It's important to note that sometimes, for seemingly no good reason, those same users can suddenly log in and work normally for a while, then it goes back to broken.

Now, I've ensured that there are no browser add-ons, plug-ins, toolbars, etc. are running. I've added our site as a trusted site and dropped the security settings to Low, I've modified the Cookie Privacy policy to "accept all" and even disabled automatic policy settings, manually forcing it to accept everything and include session cookies. Nothing appears to affect it.

Also note the web application resides on a single server. There is no load balancing, web gardens, server farms, clusters, etc. The server does reside behind an ISA server, but other than that it's pretty straight forward.

I've been searching around for days and haven't found anything actionable. Heck, sometimes I can't even reproduce it reliably. I have found a few references to people having this same problem, but they seem to be referencing an issue that was allegedly fixed in a beta or RC release (example: [IE8 loses cookies when opening a new window after a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179260/ie8-loses-cookies-when-opening-a-new-window-after-a-redirect)). These are release versions of IE, with up-to-date patches.

I'm aware that I can try to set permanent cookies instead of session cookies. However, this has drastic security implications for our application.

### Update

It seems that the problem automagically goes away when the user is added as a Local Administrator on the machine. Only time will tell if this change permanently (and positively) affects this problem.

Time to bust out ProcMon and see if there is a resource access problem.

### Update #2

It seems there are multiple angles to what appears to be a singular problem. I reported long ago that making the user a local administrator seemed to help. And it did, for a number of users. Of course, that's not really a solution, but it did let us hobble along.

Then more users started reporting the issue, and the admin fix was not helping. The users seemed to be mostly Win7, but Vista was also affected. They also seemed to mostly be 64-bit installations.

Setting the TabProcGrowth to 0 or 1 (either worked) as suggested by some members below seems to have largely addressed the issue. So, I'm going to move my accepted answer to the first person that suggested that, as it has had significantly more impact.

This has been an incredibly frustrating issue to attempt to solve, since it is difficult to reproduce and often occurs with users that I do not have direct communication with, or by the time I get to them it doesn't appear to be working. All I can say is something is not right with the session merging feature, but I don't have much data to feed to Microsoft to find a permanent fix.

Comment: Has anyone found a real solution for this?  Our testing has determined this to be specific to IE8 on a 64 bit machine.  IE8 on a 32 bit machine works correctly for this scenario.  Tried the 32 bit and 64 bit version of IE8 on the 64 bit machine, and they both had the same issue.

The testing was done using Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition.

Thanks,
DK

Comment: I'm still getting this issue. Very painful

Comment: This also seems to occur if you open links with target="_blank". Microsoft are a bunch of [rest of comment self-censored due to extreme language]

Comment: @MadHalfling Are you aware of any sort of work-around?  Is there some other way to open up a new window besides _blank that does allow cookie propagation across windows?

Comment: @CydeWeys AFAIK there is no workabround, apart from the registry setting to change the threshold. See the accepted answer's link for more details - it's beyond innept

Comment: A very similar issue is happening in an Office 365 snap-in app that uses OAuth and multi-tenant login to redirect a user to their organization's sign in page. In this case, when the snap-in opens a new window, we 'lose' our authorization with respect to our snap-in, even though the user successfully logs into their tenant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is 'new' functionality in IE8!

Checkj out the IE8 blog below to read about it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/askie/archive/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx

IE8 can use multiple processes for handling an x number of IE windows. When you cross a process space, you loose your cookies (Asp.Net session ID seems to be retained over this process boundry).

I personally think it's broken or a bug. As we know, when browing to the 'same domain target' cookies should be maintained and resent. That IE8 has different processing behavior for security.. Great! that it is behaving badly and 'drops cookies even if going to the same target domain in another window' is just a bug in my view.

You can modify the number of processes IE8 uses through the internet explorer options ehh.. modifying a registry setting!!!!!! (this is what makes it a bug in my view. IE providing a UI to modify these settings would make it 'enterprise level acceptable'.

Regard,

Marvin Smit

Comment: Enterprises can modify the setting via GP, but that's really missing the point: IE will ensure that the new process has the old processes cookies. If it didn't, that would be a bug, and such bugs were squashed before the final version was released.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT I think the bug is still there, if more erratic in release. I agree and personally also think it *is* a bug. I can replicate this behaviour by stressing/loading a machine and then opening lots of IE windows. The behaviour described where cookies are received from server and in very next request are *not* sent by the browser seems incorrect.

Comment: Idiocy by design - the Asp.Net site is a hard cookie, which is why it works across processes - if you try this on Yahoo and just use session cookies by unchecking the "Keep me signed in" option the same thing happens. I agree with your bug assessment, as it doesn't always happen (if the algorithm decides not to start a new process) so you can open the same link in a new tab several times and sometimes it will persist the logged in session and sometimes it won't, and will challenge you for your credentials.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple possibilities behind this -

- [UAC & Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Had to crop up!!). Specifically, look for protected mode behavior.
- This could be an actual problem with the [Session Merging feature in IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx). More so because opening a new window via the <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> shortcut causes the cookies to be magically sent in your case.
- An issue with an older build of IE (I know you have stated that your customers are using the latest build). You might want to check the details available at Microsoft Connect for bug IDs [408806](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=408806) and [392032](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=392032).

Comment: It's not protected mode.  

It is related to the Loosely-Coupled IE feature, which is related to Session Merging. 

We had a bunch of bugs here during the IE8 Beta and RC. We fixed those. I believe all open bugs in this space have been fixed in RTM + Full patches, so be sure that the user has all of the latest patches installed.

If you can send me a .SAZ file (Fiddler export) I'll have a look.

Comment: The affected users all definitely appear to have the latest patches, and are a mix of both Vista and XP. However, I can't help shake the feeling that there might be a regression here.

However, the fact that I can't reliably reproduce this is making it difficult to prove or disprove this.

When I can get this level of access to a problematic machine, I'm going to try following the Hyperthreading recourse seen in the Beta and RC bugs.

I'll be sure to send along a Fiddler export as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We solved this problem by changing the "Set tab process growth" to 0.

Although, we didn't have protected mode turned on and the zone was "Intranet". Evidently this is a problem/bug with Windows 7 64Bit as others have stated.

This page (#4) lead me to the solution: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/04/07/seven-things-you-should-known-about-ie-8/

Answer (score 2):

Near as I can tell, another change to cookies across tabs just went live in [this security update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2888505) from November 12, 2013 that is breaking functionality in our app in all versions of IE.  We're doing OpenID auth in a popup window so as to not have to redirect the user away from the page they were browsing when they first clicked the Login link.  The session cookie for the login is correctly being sent down in the request in the popup window, but it never gets seen by the main browser window, so the next request to the server doesn't have that session cookie on it like it should, and thus logging in never actually works.

Does anyone have any possible solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem since IE 5, so I only use session's variables in modal pop-up windows...
When I open a non-modal pop-up window, I replace all session's variables with ASP.NET cache and new object collections... 
But it's very tiresome!

Other browsers (i.e. Firefox) don't have this problem...

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem on IE6,7 and 8 .The scenario is parent window(1) opens a modal window(2),modal window has a link to a non-modal window (3). I used to get a different session Id in the 3rd window.

Workaround mentioned here fixed the issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831678

Answer (score 1):

Since IE8 we (and our customers) are also experiencing the same issue. We have an asp service for creating forms. This application uses new windows for adding elements or managing user accounts e.g. Randomly (when opening a new window), the application doesn't get the required session id for authentication allong with other 'permanent' cookies. Hence, the session id is a temporary cookie. Most of the time it goes well, but other times the session is broken every time a new window is opened. We have to advise our customers to close all IE windows and start over again.

As a web developer I use IE extensively. Personally, I am not experiencing the above issue. But I think a related one. A few times a day IE totally hangs (does not respond anymore) when opening a new window. When I kill a certain IE process using the task manager, IE starts responding again. But in most cases it's better to start all over with a clean new instance of IE. For this reason I just kill the process with the least ram usage which causes all IE processes to quit.

Microsoft saying these issues/bugs are squashed in the final version does not give me trust of their effort solving the issue still be experienced.

Answer (score 1):

I also found a workable fix for this problem. There seems to be a problem with how IE8 handles opening servlets in another window with a relative path such as /test. It seems to be opening a new session as well as a new window. Our workable fix is that instead of opening a new window with a relative path, we just used a jsp page. So when we navigate to a URL, we do not navigate to /test anymore.We navigate to a specific file. In the jsp file, we forward the request to the relative path. This seems to work, which is kind of awkward, since the only difference is that we are placing a specific file in between.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is actually a bug in IE; I have reported it here to see what feedback I get: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83bb3b91-1c1f-4d51-9281-9bc5f51d3640/log-in-fails-cookie-is-not-sent-to-originating-tab?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: This proved to be both our fault and IE's. We set two cookies and for some reason, IE killed them both. We will remove one of these cookies and hopefully have that take care of the problem. The issue with IE killing them both has been escalated to the engineering team.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar, though not identical problem. We load a webpage that opens a popup with `window.open()` into an IE browser control. On machines that have either IE6 and IE8, the popup window is always assigned a new SessionID by ASP when launched from the control. However, when launched from a normal browser (IE or Firefox), the popup window gets the existing SessionID.

I can see when launching from the control that a new `iexplore.exe` process is spawned; thus the session loss behavior makes sense given what has been mentioned about in-memory cookies not being carried over to the new process.

I'm still trying to figure out a workaround myself ...

**Update**

Figured out a workable fix! It is possible to subclass `SessionIDManager` and specify that this class should be used instead of the default (`<sessionState sessionIDManagerType="...">` in *Web.config*). The subclass can look for a query parameter containing the existing session id in an override of `CreateSessionID()`, and return it if found. This essentially allows a page to request being "merged" into an existing session it has knowledge of.

The call to `window.open()` then simply needs that query parameter specified in its URL.

Haw-Bin

Comment: Can you post a code sample of your solution please.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with PHP5 and IE8. When opening one certain popup window in Javascript with window.open, IE8 lost the session cookie and forced the user to login agan.

Meanwhile, other popup windows worked OK.

The culprit turned out to be an image tag. The template system generates image src = values dynamically and a missing image resulted in an image tag with an empty src clause (

I supect this has something to do with IE interpreting the empty src-tag as an insecure URL and isolating the session in the popup without informing the user.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue with using session variables to pass values to a pop-up window.  I just ended up writing the values to a persistent cookie and then reading the cookie in the popup window.  This may not work with the issue you were having with forms authentication, but if are just using session variables to pass some values to a window in IE8, persistent cookies seems to have worked for me.

edit: see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179260/ie8-loses-cookies-when-opening-a-new-window-after-a-redirect?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Use the LocalStoprage method to reset the value in parent window.
localStorage("Key")="Value";//Javascript

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit better please.