# ASP.NET 2.0 Session variables lost in pop up window in IE 7 when deployed on server

Tags: internet-explorer

I am opening popup window form java script like this.

window.showModalDialog(popUrl, name, appearence )

In chrome it works fine. but in IE my session variables are lost.

Please help!!!!!

Thanks

Comment: IE 8 had it working all the time but in IE 7 it was inconsistent. Iam thinking to get rid of session in my popups to avoid such issue. but it will be lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question:

[IE8 losing session cookies in popup windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324181/ie8-losing-session-cookies-in-popup-windows)