# MVC 2 authentication. The cookie faster lose a validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, cookies

After a convert MVC yo MVC 2 I get problems with authentication. In this project used standart membership.

```
[HandleError]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceFactory _modelFactory;

    public AccountController(IServiceFactory _modelFactory)
    {
        this._modelFactory = _modelFactory;
    }


    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!this.ValidateLogOn(userName, password))
        {
            return View();
        }

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, rememberMe);
        //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return RedirectToAction(ControllerNaming.Action<AdminController>(x => x.Dashboard()), ControllerNaming.Name<AdminController>());
    }

    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction(ControllerNaming.Action<HomeController>(x => x.Default()), ControllerNaming.Name<HomeController>());
    }


    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity is WindowsIdentity)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Windows authentication is not supported.");
        }
    }

    #region Validation Methods

    private bool ValidateLogOn(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("username", "You must specify a username.");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("password", "You must specify a password.");
        }
        if (!this.IsValidateUserNameAndPassword(userName, password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("password", "Password is not valid.");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        return ModelState.IsValid;
    }

    private bool IsValidateUserNameAndPassword(string userName, string password)
    {
        IUser user = this._modelFactory.UserService.Login(userName, password);

        return user.IsValid;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and setting

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="3000" />
</authentication>
```

I check in browse and I see the authentication cookie. But application want again login after 1-5 minutes if I'm nothing to do at page

sessionState

```
<sessionState timeout="150" ></sessionState>
```

But I have some one interesting fact. This application working fine at local IIS. But when I moved at Hosting I get this problem.

Comment: Does your web.config have a `<sessionState>` tag?  Could you please add the contents of it to your question or check the timeout attribute?

Comment: <sessionState timeout="150" ></sessionState>

Comment: Did you confirm that rememberMe is true?

Comment: Yes I'm confirm that rememberMe is true

Comment: OK, next question. Does this problem occur on all browsers, or just one/some?  Does your site use pop-up windows at all?  Earlier today I witnessed what appears to be an obscure IE8 bug that I hadn't seen before, discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1324181/20766

Comment: Pop-up not used. Yes problem in all browsers

Comment: When I'm return version MVc 1. Authentication work fine