# Session data lost on redirect - Kohana 3.0

Tags: php, session, kohana-3

I have an app written in Kohana 3.0 using native sessions. In less than 1% of my users, the session data is lost on a redirect.

When this happens the user cannot log in with any browser on their computer. They can, however, log in on a different computer. They seem to all be on windows OS but different versions.

It was a stand alone app but now it is launched (in a new window) through another website for a subset of users. It is only those users that are having this problem.

I cannot recreate the problem and am guessing that it has something to do with the users' computers. Is there any kind of anti-virus software or anything that messes with session data?

---

My session config is:

```
'native' => array(
'name' => 'myappname',
'encrypted' => TRUE,
'lifetime' => 1209600,
),
```

I have added a lot of debug logging and a user that lost session data is here:

```
2013-02-04 20:09:16 --- DEBUG: EC ******* start login - IP = 67.255.224.46
2013-02-04 20:09:16 --- DEBUG: EC cgl/user - logged in = 1 - IP = 67.255.224.46
2013-02-04 20:09:16 --- DEBUG: EC cgl/user ------- before redirect - user = 5 - logged in = 1 - redirect = bookshelf - $_SESSION =  id = 431a0b849f91a37d29b58a23bf130fe9  [ auth_user=>12874  ] - IP = 67.255.224.46
2013-02-04 20:09:16 --- DEBUG: bookshelf/before ~~~~~ NO USER = 0 - logged in = 0 - $_SESSION =  id = d502f35a37c7af525c1bda5476c9daac [  ]  - IP = 67.255.224.46
2013-02-04 20:09:17 --- ERROR: You must log in to see this page. $_SESSION = id = 66bf60812be3f6b5e3c1df42916e7f18 [ ], IP = 67.255.224.46
```

The "before redirect" is directly before my `Request::instance()->redirect('bookshelf');` The "bookshelf/before" is in my controller's before method.

A user that did not lose session data has logs that look like this:

```
2013-02-04 14:17:53 --- DEBUG: EC ******* start login - IP = 98.89.106.34
2013-02-04 14:17:53 --- DEBUG: EC cgl/user - logged in = 1 - IP = 98.89.106.34
2013-02-04 14:17:53 --- DEBUG: EC cgl/user ------- before redirect - user = 5 - logged in = 1 - redirect = bookshelf - $_SESSION =  id = 227e70d49c796ce03dc9f52d8a7b571e  [ auth_user=>13246  ] - IP = 98.89.106.34
2013-02-04 14:17:53 --- DEBUG: EC bookshelf/before - logged in = 1 - $_SESSION =  id = 227e70d49c796ce03dc9f52d8a7b571e  [ auth_user=>13246 last_active=>1360005473  ]  - IP = 98.89.106.34
2013-02-04 14:17:53 --- DEBUG: EC bookshelf/index - logged in = 1  - $_SESSION =  id = 227e70d49c796ce03dc9f52d8a7b571e  [ auth_user=>13246 last_active=>1360005473 school_id=>  ] - IP = 98.89.106.34
```

Comment: Could you clarify your definition of a standalone app? When it's launched in a new window, is it from a user click on the other website? Also you may want to see if this is related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324181/ie8-losing-session-cookies-in-popup-windows

Comment: For the original app, the user goes to the website url, logs in, and redirected to the bookshelf. As part of the other application, the user logs into their website and clicks a link to our app. Our app is launched in a new window, and the user automatically logged in and redirected to the bookshelf.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with sessions in Kohana 3.3. I solved it by changing, **`'encrypted' => FALSE`** in my config/session.php. Like this...

```
'database' => array(
        'name' => 'session_database', // Make sure the name is unique for each session type
        'encrypted' => FALSE,
        'lifetime' => 43200, // 43200 is 12hrs session time
        'group' => 'default',
        'table' => 'sessions',
        'columns' => array(
            'session_id'  => 'session_id',
            'last_active' => 'last_active',
            'contents'    => 'contents'
        ),
```