# jquery cookie not working - same domain different folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a html page in a sub directory:

```
http://mydomain.com/subDir/mag.html
```

That file sets a cookie using $.cookie, then loads the main index page like so:

```
$.cookie("something",value);
alert( $.cookie("something") );  // test code: this shows the cookie correctly
window.open("../index.html","_self");
```

But when I do that, I loose the cookie (shows as undefined). If I put mag.html on the same directory level as index.html, it works.

I can work around this but was wondering why this is so, since the domain hasn't changed.

Comment: which browser are you testing this?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324181/ie8-losing-session-cookies-in-popup-windows`: is why I was asking

Comment: I'm using Chrome. In this instance, Chrome and IE are working the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One path doesn't have access to another's cookies, unless it is a lower level path (that is, closer to the 'core').

Your cookie is set in `subDir`. You have to set it to the path of the main index file so to be able to access this cookie there.

In order to set a custom path, you will have to pass a third argument to the `$.cookie()` method, which is a configuration object.

So: `$.cookie("something", value, { path: '/' });`

Comment: "One path doesn't have access to another's cookies, ..." You're right ... However, according to the mozilla docs about [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie#Security), you can bypass such limitation using iframes and javascript ...