# Session Expired in Asp.Net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

Some users close all the browsers and they open IE8 again and they get the message "Session Expired" in the login page, which is strange, and it only happens sometimes.

The conditions to show that message are:

```
var sessionTimedOut = Session.IsNewSession && Request.Headers["Cookie"] != null && Request.Headers["Cookie"].Contains(ASPNET_SESSION_COOKIE);
```

And normally all cookies disapear when the browser is closed, because that is the scope of these cookies.

So what could be causing this condition to be true?

Comment: Edit: I could replicate the issue by waiting the session to expire, then killing the browser on Task Manager, then opening the browser and going explicitly to the login page (http://myserver.com/Web/Authentication/Login), but I don't believe my users are killing the browser - I believe they don't even know how to do that....

Comment: it might be related to specific IE8 behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324181/ie8-losing-session-cookies-in-popup-windows. Can you ask your users what actions exactly they are doing?

Comment: Just a guess, If you are using form authentication set cookie to persistent.

Comment: What is ASPNET_SESSION_COOKIE?

Comment: If you are able to reproduce it, then maybe use a tool like Fiddler to examine the HTTP request and see how the session id is being passed back to the server (ie. cookies, url, http header). Take a look at [ASP.NET State Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx) for some things to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saving the value `ASPNET_SESSION_COOKIE` yourself into the session?...or just relying on ASP.net built in sessions handler? If you are not saving by yourself, then the following scenario might have been causing the problem.

I think your condition is not properly configured to check for expired sessions.The reasons are -

1. ASP.Net by default saves `Sessions`, in `Cookie`, Therefore whenever a new session is created so does the `Cookie`.
2. Lets, consider the scenario, that a session has expired, then when the request is made 
   (that is the GET for the Login page) ASP.net is checking for a `Cookie` or `Session` and sees that it needs a new session to be created. Therefore, it creates a `Session` and saves the cookie.
3. Again, lets consider, this is the first time some one sees the page, again, the same thing will happen as 2. The condition is always true.
4. You need to save some custom `Cookie/Session` values inside the cookie/session so that you can check agains it.

I am highly suspicious that, the condition -

```
Session.IsNewSession && Request.Headers["Cookie"] != null && Request.Headers["Cookie"].Contains(ASPNET_SESSION_COOKIE);
```

is never false, Unless you are using or checking this, **before the session is handled or checked by ASP.Net.**

Comment: Let me explain better: This is the Login GET action of my LoginController.

Comment: When starting a new IE8 when all other browsers were closed Session.IsNewSession is true and Request.Headers["Cookie"].Contains(ASPNET_SESSION_COOKIE) is false, so I just present the Login form to the user.

Comment: If I start IE8, login, wait for the session and authentication/forms expiration, open a new IE8 on the login action, then: Session.IsNewSession is true and Request.Headers["Cookie"].Contains(ASPNET_SESSION_COOKIE) is true, so I'm wrongly showing on that new window that the session has expired

Comment: Now what contraditcs your theory: If I start IE8, login, wait for the session and authentication/forms expiration, CLOSE ALL BROWSERS, open a new IE8 on the login action, then: Session.IsNewSession is true and Request.Headers["Cookie"].Contains(ASPNET_SESSION_COOKIE) is false, so I'm not showing any timeout message on the Login View.