# Window.open is losing session

Tags: asp.net, session

My team have a big problem with a developed website. We have a page where We need to open three or four tabs, We used window.open and everything worked fine in testing area. But, in production with a load balancer (sticky session configured) when window.open is executed, It creates a new session, We saw in the logs that the request is redirected to other server when window.open is executed.
I've seen other links in stackoverflow like [IE8 losing session cookies in popup windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324181/ie8-losing-session-cookies-in-popup-windows?s=2|2.6282)
But the problem is that It happens also in Firefox, any clue about this kind of problem?
BTW, Our app is a ASP .Net MVC 4.5 website.

Answer (score 0):

Second part of your question is pointing to a problem on the client side.
But if I read your problem it looks like a problem on the server side.
I think that your session pool over the load balancer has a problem.

Maybe try a simple page that shows your sessionId on a page and run that in your server farm for testing. make shure that the problem is not in your app but at server level.

edit after questionar reply:
Is your cookie set domain wide?
what happens if you open more tabs manually?

Is it a browser domain cookie handler problem (then the manual tabs will not work)
Or is it a javascript handler problem. (then the manual tabs will work)

Comment: Yes, We've made many tests over the server farm. The problem is that this is happening only when It opens many tabs with window.open.